# System Generator: How to configure the pins for the signals of your design?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, pins, xilinx-system-generator, configuration

I am programming a FPGA by System Generator. I have done this design:
[image]

**I don´t know what are the respectives pins of my FPGA for the blocks of my design called 'Gateway In' and 'Gateway Out'**. I would like to check I would check the design made in my FPGA through a generator waves and a oscilloscope.
Does anyone know how to assign pins of your design if you made it using System Generator?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click the Gateway block and click to the "implementation" tab, there's a box you can tick to "Specify IOB location constraints".

You can then enter something like this in the IOB pad locations box underneath:

```
{'P22', 'P12'}
```

(if you have 2 bits, repeat as needed if you have more!).  This is for a leaded package with simple numbers on each pin.  If you're using a BGA device, the pins will be named alphanumerically.  It's explained quite well in the HELP for the Gateway blocks.

You can check this has worked by looking at the .pad file in the same directory as your .bit file was created - you should be able to find the IOBs named and see which pin they were mapped to.  (There's two versions of the pad file, one is a CSV file the other is a text table which looks fine in a monospaced font)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a '.ucf' (= user constraints file) as part of your project? Pin assignments are defined there. Something like

```
NET "some_net" LOC="F3";
```

means that the net "some_net" is connected to pin "F3". You can change these entries so that nets connect to other pins, *though you must be careful*. If you're targeting a particular board, every pin will be connected to something, and you don't want to cause contention (by assigning a 0/ground/low to a pin that's connected to 5 V, for example). Also, there are banking rules that you must adhere to, etc.